# Upgrade anonymous users not working with firebaseui and angular

Tags: angular, web, upgrade, angularfire, firebaseui

I'm using [firebaseui](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) in our angular project with [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire).

Since I need to support multiple languages I cannot use firebaseui as a npm package (and therefore all community-wrappers will not work) and must include is as a JS file.

But upgrading anonymous users isn't working. FirebaseUI always creates a new user instead of upgrading the anonymous one. The firebase instance definitely has the anonymous user logged in so firebaseUI should see him.

My setup and wrapper for firebaseui looks like this:

angular.json

```json
...
"configurations": {
  "de": {
    ...
    "scripts": [
      "src/assets/js/firebaseui__de.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```ts
...
export class AppModule {
    constructor() {
      // Attach firebase to window so FirebaseUI can access it
      (window as any).firebase = firebase;
    }
}
```

login.component.ts

```ts
...
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('firebaseui', { read: ElementRef }) private firebaseUiComp: ElementRef;

    firebaseUiAuthConfig = {
        signInFlow: 'popup',
        signInOptions: [
            {
                provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                customParameters: {
                    prompt: 'select_account'
                }
            },
            firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            {
                provider: 'apple.com'
            },
            {
                provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                // Whether the display name should be displayed in the Sign Up page.
                requireDisplayName: true
            }
        ],
        autoUpgradeAnonymousUsers: true,
        credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE,
        callbacks: {
            signInSuccessWithAuthResult: this.onSignInSuccess.bind(this),
            signInFailure: this.onSignInError.bind(this),
        }
    };


    constructor(
        private data: DataService,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.firebaseUiComp.nativeElement.innerHTML = '';

         try {
           this.data.fuiAuth.reset();
         } finally {
           this.data.fuiAuth.start(this.firebaseUiComp.nativeElement, this.firebaseUiAuthConfig);
         }
      }, 0);
    }

    onSignInError(error: any) {
        return this.ngZone.run(async () => {
            // For merge conflicts, the error.code will be
            // 'firebaseui/anonymous-upgrade-merge-conflict'.
            if (error.code !== 'firebaseui/anonymous-upgrade-merge-conflict') {
                return Promise.reject();
            }

            // merging should happen here.

            // But "onSignInError" gets never called anyway because there is no issue because upgrading fails in the first place. (firebaseUI seems not to recognize the anonymous user).

            // The credential the user tried to sign in with.
            const cred = error.credential;
            const userCred = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred);

            await this.finishLogin(userCred.user);
        });
    }

    ...

}
```

data.service.ts

```ts
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  public fuiAuth;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {
    this.fuiAuth = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.afAuth.auth);
  }

  ...
}
```

When logging in anonymously somewhere else in the app via `this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously();` or `this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCustomToken(token);` with a token of an anonymous user [afAuth: AngularFireAuth], I can see that the user gets logged in correctly (and is anonymous). But when then creating a new account via firebaseui, it just logs in the new user instead of upgrading the old one.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Currently running on the same issue and haven't figured it out. Will post here any findings.